# Invalid_scope error while login with GooglePlus sdk iOS sdk

Tags: ios, google-plus

I have downloaded latest google plus sdk for iOS and also have created the Client ID for for my application.

I have just replaced the  Client ID provided by the google sdk to the my Application's Id. when i was trying to login with the google plus its login successfully and just shows me the

Error:Invalid_scope

how can i resolve it ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste in the URL that displays in that address bar (making sure to remove your client ID or access token parameters for security)?